# Changing relative monitor positions programmatically using ChangeDisplaySettingsEx?

Tags: c#, windows

I have 3 monitors, 2 of which are 4K, and due to some games not running smoothly when the main monitor is in 4K I have set up a small C# program that change the resolution and dpi setting for the main monitor for me.

Yes, I know I can set games to automatically switch the monitor resolution for me, but I like to be able to run the games in borderless full screen so that I can easily move the mouse over to the two other monitors where I have chats and such and websites.

However, whenever I change the resolution and dpi, the monitors gets "moved around" according to the display settings, relative to each other.

For instance, if I set the main monitor (monitor #1) to 1080p, their relative setting is like this:

```
         +-------+++----------------+
         |   1   ||                 |
         +-------+|        2        |
+-------+         |                 |
|   3   |         |                 |
+-------+         +-----------------+
```

This makes it very hard moving the mouse over to the third monitor, the one on the left, as there is no overlapping coordinates. I then have to go into display settings to rearrange them, and this is why I created the program in the first place, in order to avoid having to go into display settings.

If I fix this relative position by moving the main monitor down so that they all have a common baseline, and then later set the resolution back to 4K, then it ends up as one of these two configurations:

```
                   +----------------+                           +----------------+
                   |                |                           |                |
                   |       2        |                 +-------+ |       2        |
                   |                |                 |   3   | |                |
                   +----------------+                 +-------+ +----------------+
+-------++----------------+              < or >       +----------------+
|   3   ||                |                           |                |
+-------+|       1        |                           |       1        |
         |                |                           |                |
         |                |                           |                |
         +----------------+                           +----------------+
```

I've looked in the registry, to set the DPI I adjust the values found beneath the following registry keys:

```
HKCU
 +-- Control Panel
      +-- Desktop
           +-- PerMonitorSettings
                +-- <device id>
                     +-- DpiValue (REG_DWORD)
```

There is no such setting for the position, however, the DpiValue is the only one there.

To set the resolution I use [User32.ChangeDisplaySettingsEx](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/ChangeDisplaySettingsEx.html), and I have looked into the structure being passed to it but I can't seem to see anything that would allow me to set their position.

So my question is simple, is there a way for me using ChangeDisplaySettingsEx to rearrange the relative positions of those monitors from my program, if so, which fields of that struct do I have to manipulate?

Comment: DEVMODE.dmPosition

Comment: Also need `dmFields` set to `DM_POSITION` - see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/enumeration-and-display-control). See also [this note](https://matthewvaneerde.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/programmatically-rearranging-displays/). PS `DM_POSITION` == `0x20L`.

Comment: Did I really miss a field named Position??? :P Hmm, it's actually not in the structure I have declared. OK, thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant If you would add an answer detailing that I would accept it. Turns out the DEVMODE copy I had was a bit wrong and a mix of different similar struct types that just happened to work for the things I used it for. I've since been able to write the program the way I want it and had to use the position.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you add an answer to this? It looks like it could be a good dupe target for questions about manipulating monitor positions

Comment: Sorry, no, it keeps failing and doing random rearrangement of monitors and resolutions. I still have a ways to go before I understand all the details here.